# Est-ce que « ce [truc]-là » est aussi courant en français que « that » en anglais ?

Tags: anglais, adjectifs, comparaison-de-langues, démonstratifs

En anglais, on emploie les deux adjectifs démonstratifs *this* et *that* très souvent.

En français, emploie-t-on *ce __-là* avec la même fréquence qu'en anglais ?

---

I fear my French is messy in this question, so let me be clear in English. We use *that* **very** often in English, probably even more than *this*, as a demonstrative adjective.

But in French, is *ce* usually used as a replacement for both? When is it right to use *ce __-là*?

Comment: Let us [talk about that in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6995/discussion-between-nikana-reklawyks-and-aerovistae)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sans autre moyen de décrire le phénomène, les français doivent bien utiliser *ce chien*, *cette voiture*, aussi souvent que les anglais *this dog*, *that car*. Qu'à l'oral, ça devienne souvent « [ç'te] voiture » montre combien c'est employé.

Par contre, le *-là* est pour l'essentiel réservé à l'écrit, ou bien aux cas où l'orateur veut désambiguiser son propos :

> *Non, pas ça, c'est celle-là, que je veux* (ou *cette voiture-là*).

**À l'oral**, on dira simplement « ce/cette __ », et éventuellement, **on rappellera l'objet avec un *celui-là* un peu plus loin dans la phrase, plutôt que de dire « ce __-là »**.

Answer (score 2):

En Français, on joue avec [*-ci*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/ci) et [*-là*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/l%C3%A0) pour exprimer *this* et *that*. C'est d'un usage très courant :

> — Aimes-tu ces tableaux ? 
>  — Je n'aime pas celui-ci, mais j'aime bien celui-là.

ou encore

> — Laquelle préfères-tu ? Cette voiture-ci ou cette voiture-là ?

*Ci* peut également être utilisé seul, mais [uniquement de façon familière et en opposition avec *ça*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/ci) :

> — Alors, comment vas-tu depuis tout ce temps ? 
>   — Comme ci comme ça...

ou encore

> — Tu as bientôt terminé ? 
>   — Non, j'ai encore beaucoup à faire. Appeler le médecin, répondre à l'avocat, et ci, et ça !